# Send Grid API returns error on react native app

Tags: api, react-native, sendgrid

I use send grid API for sending mail from my react native app but it returns this error.
i use this link: "https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-nodejs/blob/master/packages/mail/USE_CASES.md"

```js
sendMail(){
  const SENDGRID_API_KEY = "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";
  const sgMail = require('@sendgrid/mail');
  sgMail.setApiKey(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY);
  const msg = {
    to: 'test@example.com',
    from: 'test@example.com',
    subject: 'Sending with SendGrid is Fun',
    text: 'and easy to do anywhere, even with Node.js',
    html: '<strong>and easy to do anywhere, even with Node.js</strong>',
  };
  sgMail.send(msg);
 }
```

[image: App Screen on Android Emulator]

Comment: Have you tried doing what the error message suggests?

Comment: i am new in react native
i didn't understand that